# How to write the perfect follow up for my situation?

Tags: professionalism, hiring-process, follow-up

Two days ago, I had an interview. I was supposed to talk to the team lead and someone from HR, however the HR person did not join us. Long story short, I think the interview went quite well with the team lead. He told me we will reach out to you within 2 weeks if we're going to proceed or not for the next interview sessions. I will still have to go through 2 more sessions. As the responsibilities are a bit different than what the position entails, he also told me to think about it and get back the the HR person if you wanna proceed or not.

I want to write a follow up email to the HR person, the one that did not attend. I would like to tell her that I am actually very interested in this position and I'd like to proceed if they also want to. I also want to ask them to tell me when they're going to get back to me and if they also can give me more details about next interviews and what they will cover since I'd like to be prepared. I was thinking of the following text. Please suggest some improvements if you can.

> Dear H, I would like to thank you for the opportunity to interviewed for the X position with your organization. I had the pleasure of speaking with Mr. R, who provided me with valuable insights about the position and your company's dynamics. Meanwhile, he filled me in on the details of this position and that they may be different from the tasks of a conventional X job.
>
> After careful consideration, I am pleased to inform you that I'm more enthusiastic about the prospect of joining your team. The X position aligns perfectly with my professional aspirations and career goals, and I am confident that I can make meaningful contributions to your organization's success. Furthermore, I'd appreciate it if you let me know an estimated timeline for when to hear back from you and details regarding the next steps.
>
> Once again, thank you, and I look forward to the opportunity to contribute to your organization's continued success."

Comment: It would probably be better to not send anything

Comment: https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/6021/135112

Answer (score 4):

Maybe, it depends on the industry when it comes to sending a follow-up note after the interviews.

---

Here is my experience in the **IT industry**.

When I first graduated from college, I was very eager to write "**follow-up**" or "**Thank-you**" notes after the job interviews. This is because the job career center in my university always recommends this practice.

However, after working for a number of years, I think that it is not really necessary to send any notes to the interviewers after the interviews. They are too busy to read these notes.

---

You still can write a very simple follow-up email if you really want to.

It's likely that after working for a few years, you will think that it is not really a big deal if you don't send any note (**if you are the IT industry**).

Answer (score 0):

If you want the job, find an excuse to send them a note or an email (or both (with different contents)). Somebody called it getting your foot in the door.
Something like,

> I had a good time interviewing with Mr. Bossly last Wednesday and
> would be very pleased to be able to work for such a swell company.
> Did I mention that I have extensive experience with XYZ?  I think that
> could prove a valuable addition to your company in the junior assistant worker-bee
> position.

If you already mentioned XYZ (in a follow up communication) you could mention something relative that seems relevant. "I not only have experience with XYZ but I have dealt with Y internals extensively."

Basically, be a pest.  Be polite but persistent.